# Music playback is breaking up in Windows 10 but does not affect online meetings

Tags: windows-10, audio

When a playing back video on a Dell Latitude 5410 running Windows 10, audio will often break up (stutter) when I am doing some other stuffs. e.g. using the browser, etc.

This happens even if I am playing back music from local disk. This does not seem to be an issue with Zoom meetings (or it could be that audio breaking is common with online meeting, but definitely not as bad as music playback). Problem usually goes away after a reboot but will come back the next day or so.

The audio output devices include the built-in headphone jack, HDMI monitor and a USB headset. The issue seems more apparent with the USB headset but it still happens with the headphone jack. Audio device drivers seem to be provided by Microsoft. Task manager's graph chart did not show any unusual loads during playback.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Identifying such a problem can be difficult. From your description, it seems that after a reboot there are no problems for one entire day, so why not just shutdown for the night and reboot in the morning?